# Is it possible to control a TabControl in multiple Grids simultaneously?

Tags: c#, wpf

Below is a picture of my question.  Is it possible and if so how can I perform functions with the control in ***Tab1-Grid1*** and have the same functions be reflected in ***Tab1-Grid2*** and ***Tab1-Grid3***?

[image]

Comment: you want all three tabs to track the same selection? So changing to tab3 goes to tab3 on the other two?

Comment: Not exactly.  You can have tab1 selected in one grid and tab3 selected in another grid BUT any action in tab1-grid1 (eg: moving the blue thingie to a different cell) would move the blue thingie in tab1-grid2 and tab1-grid3.